# How to change the app name which is placed in the launcher screen

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to change the app name. Not every where. only in the launcher screen of an android.

Not inside the app or in the installation screen.

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Manifest.xml` file should be similar to this:

```
<application
    ....
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="myLabel"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
     ....
 ....
```

As you can see every `Activity` node has a `label` attribute. Changing this changes only the activity label (not all over the application)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `android:label` attribute of the main `Activity` in your Android Manifest (the one that starts when the Launcher icon is pressed)